# how to write "include path(folder that contain header)" for IntelliSense Configurations in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

the directory of the header is `C:\MinGW\include\stdio.h`. How can I convert it to the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in VS Code, first use the command `Ctrl + Shift + P` to pull up the Command Pallette. Then, type in the command `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)`. This will pull up a `json` file in which you can include paths to header files to be included for IntelliSense. The `json` should look something like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

To add a custom path, according to the `json` [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference), you can specify another path under the `"includePath` property. Here is what you should change this `json` property to, according to your custom header's location:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/MinGW/include/"
            ],
```

Note that I did not include the actual header file, as the path must point to a folder that contains the header file rather than to the header itself. Also notice that you must use forward slashes rather than back slashes.

Comment: I still got "{
 "resource": "/C:/Stuff/code/Cstudy/try.c",
 "owner": "C/C++",
 "code": "1696",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\\Stuff\\code\\Cstudy\\try.c).",
 "source": "C/C++",
 "startLineNumber": 1,
 "startColumn": 1,
 "endLineNumber": 1,
 "endColumn": 19
}" error I going to make a new post

Comment: Please don't make a new post, I'm sure I or somebody else will be able to help you solve this issue on this post.

Comment: Thank you, this will greatly contribute to less clutter on the forum

Comment: sorry, I solved, it is a stupid mistake that I misspelled it to studio.h